# Example of marrying Python's paramiko and pexpect?

Tags: pexpect

The documentation for the `pxssh` portion of `pexpect` suggests using `paramiko` but then gives no examples.  So does this mean "use `paramiko` and ignore `pexpect` completely" or is there a way to create an `ssh` session using `paramiko` and then drive it using `pexpect`?

If the latter, anyone got a very simple example of how to do this?

Comment: You might instead look at this [paramiko-expect extension](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect) if it suffices.

Comment: Thanks, that might be enough for what I need.